# Вопрос по метаклассам

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучаю метаклассы в python. Немогу понять одну вещь. Допустим есть код:

```
class Meta(type):
    print('meta')
class User(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__ User')
    print(1)
x = User()
```

Немогу понять, почему код выполняется в том порядке, в котором он выполняется. Разве не должно быть все в точности наоборот, т.е. сначала исполняться команда `print('__init__ User')`, затем команда `print(1)` и только после этого каманда `print('meta')`? Почему команды выполняются в порядке противоположенном, указанному мной? Хотелось бы прояснить этот момент.

Comment: А вы попробуйте создать несколько объектов

Comment: @insolor Надо оформить как ответ, а то чего вопрос висит то )

Comment: @CrazyElf, оформил)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метаклассы тут ни при чем.

Весь код внутри классов, но вне его методов, выполняется при объявлении класса, до создания объекта. По порядку у вас объявлен сначала класс `Meta` - выводится "meta", ниже объявлен класс `User` - выводится 1, потом вы создаете объект - выводится `"__init__ User"`.